# Symfony 3 - Problem with variables in my modal

Tags: php, symfony, modal-dialog

I'm developing a site where users can download packages. My users have a user type.

In my admin page, when I want to delete a package normally, everything works. But when I want to use a modal as confirmation, I have the impression that I place my variables wrong (the id of the package to delete, with the id of the user type to which it is attached).

I use the id of the user type because a package can belong to several types, and when I delete a package I want to be able to choose if I want to remove it from a single type.

I have :

**Without modal :**

```
 <a href="{{ path('paquets_delete', { 'id': uneInfo['package'].id, 'type':unType['typeUtilisateur'] }) }}" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer</a>
```

It's work.

**With modal :**

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal-{{ uneInfo.id }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer</button>
            {{ macro.create_delete_modal('deleteModal-'~uneInfo.id, 'Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce package ? ', path('paquets_delete', {'id':uneInfo.id, 'type': unType['typeUtilisateur']})) }}
```

**The modal :**

```
{%- macro create_delete_modal(id, body, deleteLink) -%}
    {% filter spaceless %}
    <div id="{{ id }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Supprimer?</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>{{ body }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="{{ deleteLink }}" class="btn btn-primary">Supprimer</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfilter %}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

I think it's because of my typeUtilisateur which is not correctly insered on the modal, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you call your create_delete_modal macro, you pass a path built with the param `'id':uneInfo.id` instead of your link example where you pass the param `uneInfo['package'].id`. Is it a typo here in your message or should it be your problem cause ?

Comment: Thin, yes it's just a typo. I had meanwhile modified my application and I forgot to replace the unInfo.id by anInfo ['package']. Id on the site. But the problem remains the same, excuse me.

Comment: If you inspect the rendered html. May you have multiple modals with the same id ? If yes, the bootstrap javascript can not open the required one !